# NuxtJS meta tags are dynamically generated but crawlers pick up the default one

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, meta-tags, vue-meta

I'm using server side rendered Nuxt2 in universal mode and asyncData function on a page to fetch information for dynamic meta tags. I'm generating tags and putting them to head()

Tags are correctly generated and I can see the dynamic tags on that page.

The problem is that when I paste the link to any og tags verification site or debugger - I get the tags present in nuxt.config.js and not the dynamic one from the page. You can see it for yourself [here](https://youtalky.com/bookle/YTzHALg). I even waited a day (as this was one of suggestions I found on stack)

What might be causing it? Middleware? Done default settings? I set up target to server and middleware to not work on that particular page to be 100% sure it's not middleware.

I am out of ideas.

Would be grateful for any.

Comment: The url you posted shows a server error

Comment: I made it work. I will post a detailed description soon!

Comment: did you find out how to fix it?